# For a function pointer func_ptr,(*func_ptr)() invokes the function.But why are (****func_ptr)() or (***func_ptr)() valid?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

Suppose `func_ptr` is a function pointer to the function `test()`.Then we know that can invoke the function `test()` using this pointer as

```
   (*func_ptr)();
```

But I was told today that even `(***func_ptr)()` or `(**********func_ptr)()` ,ie with any number of  ***** works.Why is it so?What is the reason.I was briefly told the reason in a comment but I just can't make sense of it.This is what I was told:

> Well, when you dereference a function pointer, you get an expression of function type (technically a "function designator"). However, when used in most contexts, such a function expression will be implicitly converted back to a function pointer that points to itself. (This is similar to how in most contexts, an expression of array type will be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.) You can repeat this "loop" as many times as you want.

Can anyone explain in simple words in a more detailed manner?

Comment: I don't know how it could be any simpler. Basically, it goes `function pointer --dereference--> function --implicitly converts to--> function pointer --dereference--> etc...`

Comment: So we need even number of asterisk symbols?

Comment: No, because AFAIK, every time you dereference it, it's implicitly converted back to a function pointer. In fact, you can invoke the function without the star at the beginning too (i.e. just `func_ptr()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to consider what dereferencing a function pointer might mean.  Technically it could be given a meaning, a function pointer points to code so dereferencing it gives the machine code instruction at the pointed-to address.  But what does that buy you?  What are you going to do with the instruction?  For that matter, what is supposed to happen on a machine whose instructions have a variable length, such as CISC processors like x86?

Clearly there is no clean answer to such questions.  So the C language designers could have opted to just outlaw dereferencing function pointers.  Or they could have specified that dereferencing a function pointer has no effect and produces the exact same pointer value.  They went for the latter.

So any number of * have no effect, as you observed.  And the sane choice is to use none.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.If someone like you found my question worthy of answering,I don't care if it got downvoted!!

Comment: "Or they could have specified that dereferencing a function pointer has no effect and produces the exact same pointer value. They went for the latter." However, dereferencing a function pointer and the function pointer itself are not always the same in the language. Consider `&*func_ptr` vs. `&func_ptr`; or `sizeof(*func_ptr)` vs. `sizeof(func_ptr)`.